# Unable to connect to the remote server in CRM 2011 Plugin

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I'hv implemented one CRM 2011 plugin which sends sms to Main Phone of Account record on create. But I'm getting an error saying **"Unable to connect to the remote server."** Below is the piece of code used in plugin.

```
    public static void send(string uid, string password, string message, string no)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myReq =
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx?uid=" + uid + "&pwd=" + password +
        "&msg=" + message + "&phone=" + no + "&provider=way2sms");

        HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse(); //Getting error in this line
        System.IO.StreamReader respStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream());
        string responseString = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        respStreamReader.Close();
        myResp.Close();
    }
```

Whats the solution to resolve this error?

Comment: Not sure if it explains your issue, but you should look into whether you need to URL-encode/escape the various parameters you're injecting into the URL. Also, have you confirmed whether you can retrieve the URL in question manually?

Comment: I run the same code in Console application, its sending sms without any error (even when manually pasted the URL).

Comment: Can you get more error information from the failed request? Also, can you post the full error / exception information?

Comment: Inner exception: "No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refuse it 118.139.172.1:80"

Answer (score 3):

If you are running this Plug-in as Sandboxed, there are [some limitations by default on the Outbound URI pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx):

> These default Web access restrictions are defined in a registry key on the server running the Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.HostService.exe
>   process. The value of the registry key can be changed by the System
>   Administrator according to business and security needs. The registry
>   key path on the server is:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSCRM\SandboxWorkerOutboundUriPattern
>
> The key value is a regular expression string that defines the Web
>   access restrictions. The default key value is:
>
> "^http[s]?://(?!((localhost[:/])|([.*])|([0-9]+[:/])|(0x[0-9a-f]+[:/])|(((([0-9]+)|(0x[0-9A-F]+)).){3}(([0-9]+)|(0x[0-9A-F]+))[:/]))).+";
>
> By changing this registry key value, you can alter the allowed Web
>   access for sandboxed plug-ins.

Comment: What if the plugin is *NOT* sandboxed?